# Is there a way to hide closed or migrated questions?

Tags: feature-request, support, migration, closed-questions

Currently on [the front page](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=newest) (when ordered by newest and have 50 to a page marked) there are 13 [closed] or migrated questions. That's approximately a quarter. Is there any way to hide these questions from view?

Not sure if this is a support question (the feature is there but I don't know where it is) or a feature-request (it's no there yet) so I've tagged it with both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Heh, stumbled on this just after I saw this question. If you go to your priviledges, you'll see something new at the top of the list; Trusted Users.

In the description, there is:

> **What is a trusted user**
>
> Trusted users are allowed to perform
>   trusted actions, including:
>
> ```
> * Vote to delete posts scored -1 and lower
> * Vote to delete questions immediately after they are closed (even if they are new)
> * Edit all tag wikis on the site
> ```

Note the second bullet.

Yes, they recently implemented a solution for that - however I don't see many active users even close (Excluding John Conde) who have the rep for it.

Comment: Good find. But as you say, there are no users even close to being able to do this. Also, if a question is just redirecting to another site, then is it necessary to have them on this one? Maybe leave it for the user that posted the question, but is it necessary for everyone to see it?

Comment: A redirected question should linger for a day or two at most, then be automatically deleted. That would be something to take up with the SE team. I agree with you 100%.

Comment: If we can come up with some guidelines as when to delete questions I'm all for clearing them out. [This one is probably a good example](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/9241/customizing-booking-form-plugin-closed).