# Sharing The Love - CLOSED Questions Saga

Tags: discussion, moderators

So I did my usual stuff today and logged onto Pro Webmasters and kinda got thinking about all the Questions that are being marked [CLOSED] and how this would look like to new users of the site.

I'm not sure if everyone would agree but a page front page with *25%-50% topics with [CLOSED]* in my honest opinion doesn't look very welcoming to new community members..
This has more and likely been discussed multiple times throughout the meta community but I guess this would be from from stacks that have fewer members than others, which I'll explain more later on, if your sure not what I'm referring too.

There are other ways you could look at this issue and these are on one hand you have people seeing [CLOSED] everywhere so they may be more inclined to read the FAQ before posting but then on the other hand we still regularly receive questions regardless.

So I believe that a page that front page that contains hardly any CLOSED questions would look more welcoming to new community members as well as displaying more results without filtering for returning members. Reverting back to what I said about stacks with fewer community members, basically I imagine this is a common problem with stacks that have fewer members than the big stacks due to the 10K mark which allows users vote delete questions, this was covered here: [Is there a way to hide closed or migrated questions?](https://webmasters.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/422/is-there-a-way-to-hide-closed-or-migrated-questions)

I saw John's comment but sadly the link that he refers to in the guidelines doesn't exist so I'm unable to comment any further on that. But hopefully john will be able to give us some further insight.

> If we can come up with some guidelines as when to delete questions I'm
>   all for clearing them out. This one is probably a good example. – John
>   Conde♦ Feb 16 '11 at 16:19

Now assuming I'm correct and John or any other moderator for that matter doesn't come say this isn't the case I'm assuming we need more 10K users that have the ability to clean up the site via vote deleting 'closed unanswered`.

**Sharing the love with an upvote 'with good reason'**

So here's the thing at the current rate of the rep being distributed we will not have enough 10K users this time next year which again, I dunno if others agree this put more work for the moderators as well as other things. My proposal is that we are more 'Willing to share the love', by no means am I asking that people go crazy, but if you have a spare moment rather than looking at only unanswered questions take a look at an accepted answer or at least one that has been answered and if you feel that someone has left a good answer and you believe it too be correct then share the love with a up vote as this will help the community as a whole, never-mind give people little fluffy feelings receiving there virtual votes :)

I'm keen to what moderators have to say on this matter and I apologize in an advance if I got how the 10K works wrong, also any comments by the community as usual are welcomed, flame away ;)

Answer (score 3):

My understanding is that this is what we should be doing regardless of any special effort.

If you see a thoughtful question that will be useful to others, upvote it.

If you see a thoughtful answer that will be useful to others, upvote it if it is technically accurate (even if it's not the accepted answer and *especially* contributes to a deeper understanding of the problem which the question refers to).

Answer (score 3):

We should not be deleting closed and migrated questions just so that they don't appear on the homepage.

When a question is closed or migrated, it still is available and users can learn from it (even if that learning is just figuring out where to go to ask a similar question).   Closed questions can also be edited for improvement by the original poster which automatically puts them in the re-open queue.

Deletion should be for spam only.

If a question is deleted, it looks much better when it has a specific comment saying why it was deleted.  I would suggest that we strive to do so.  Write a comment on all closed questions letting folks know specifically how the question could have been improved.

Comment: Hi Stephen but I was kinda referring to questions that will never see the light of day, exact duplicates, extremely off topic and so on.

Comment: I would support deleting duplicates that are exactly the same (user copies and pastes a question).  Duplicates that are not quite exact often use different keywords and make it possible for future users to find the question more easily. Off-topic questions should remain closed but un-deleted.

Comment: Duplicates are the one thing you probably don't want to be deleting: they are useful markers that get people to the right question when they search using alternate wording. All other closed questions should be deletion candidates. If they aren't getting edited to make them openable, they should eventually get removed. You don't want the garbage collection process to happen too fast, but they should eventually get removed.